# Heroku app accessible only on device which I created it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, redux, mern

I want to deploy my app, but I have some problems with it.
Here's some details:

- Free plan on heroku
- All I can see on other devices is the backgrond image/collor/pattern
- Errors on other devices(mostly connected with redux):

  - On Firefox(on Windows):
    [image: Console errors on firefox]
  - On Chrome(on Windows):
    [image]

On Internet Explorer I didn't see any console errors( but it only shows background).

ps. I have one additional question about ssl certificate. How to add it(step by step).

Comment: Do you see more when you are locally running the web application? SSL is handled by Heroku you don't need to do anything there. Just serve over http and they automatically make it https.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined. From that I read that's connected with redux dev tools, but I can't expect everybody to get it installed. I will post store.js file on next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion. I found the problem, that I forced devtools in production here's the fixed part.
store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly'; //that's the solution
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
  )
);

export default store;
```